# kivy async on_click function

Tags: python, oop, kivy, python-asyncio

currently I'm making an app with `kivy`, edge `gpt` and `asyncio`. Edge `gpt` requires an `asyncio`, so the problem is

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MyBoxLayout.ask' was never awaited
   self.dispatch('on_press')
 RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Please, help me..

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import asyncio
from EdgeGPT import Chatbot as Bing, ConversationStyle
import json
import os

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        self.input = TextInput(hint_text="Enter your name")
        self.add_widget(self.input)

        self.button =  Button(text="Submit")
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.ask)
        self.add_widget(self.button)

    async def ask(self, prompt):
        bing = Bing(cookie_path=os.path.expanduser('cookies.json'))
        async for res in bing.ask_stream(
            prompt=prompt,
            conversation_style=ConversationStyle.balanced,
        ):
            try:
                res = res[1]['item']['messages'][1]
                res = f"{res['adaptiveCards'][0]['body'][0]['text']}"
            except Exception:
                res = res[1]

        replacements = [('[]', ''), ('^', ''), ('[1]', ''),
                        ('[2]', ''), ('[3]', ''), ('[4]', ''), ("←[2K", "")]
        for char, replacement in replacements:
            if char in res:
                res = res.replace(char, replacement)
        print(res)

#
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBoxLayout()
        asyncio.run(ask())
         

if __name__ == '__main__':

    MyApp().run()
```

i need kivy to get user input on click  and to print edge gpt's output